# why is echo "ens6f1" > interpreting as ns6f1 ie with out "e"

Tags: linux, linux-networking, ubuntu-14.04, bonding

i am trying to execute

```
echo "ens6f1" > /sys/class/net/bond0/bonding/slaves
```

but getting error:

bond0: Interface **ns6f1** does not exist!

is this an "echo" issue or some issue with the file which i am trying to write.

ubuntu 14.04.4

```
ip l l ens6f1
25: ens6f1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 14:02:ec:67:fd:95 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: You probably got a non-printing character in there somewhere. Type it in again, and don't copy and paste it.

Comment: i tried that,but unfortunatley it doesnt work.
but works for regular file.

echo ens6f1 > hi
root@node-2:/root/# cat hi
ens6f1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to `echo '+ens6f1'` to add an interface, note the plus sign. The error message you see comes from the kernel code, which strips the first character (operation sign, plus or minus, in your case a letter `e`) and treats the rest as an interface name. Before any operation is considered, interface name validity is checked, so you get that error..